# How do I create a network replicated drives on my windows computers?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, home-networking, file-sharing

I want to have a directory that I can share over my home wifi network with all three of my windows computers(two windows 10 and one windows 11. Right now windows 11 computer is not that important to me.) I want all three of my computers to have a copy of this directory and I need their copies to be kept in sync with each other.

What I mean by this is that, when I add or delete or edit or rename a file to/from/in this directory I want that change to be replicated to the directories on all three computers. In the event that one of these computer's hard drive dies, I should still have a copy of this directory left on my other computers. Also, two of these computers are laptops, so if I take a laptop with me when I am traveling, I should still have a copy of this directory with me.

How do I achieve this goal? Is this even possible? Please don't recommend dropbox to me as the files I am going to be storing on these drives are very sensitive(scanned copy of my immigration documents/passport etc). I don't want these files to be shared over the internet.

Comment: I don't think Windows can natively keep folders synced across computers. Given more than two computers and users, set up the folders on a central computer and ask that they reside there and not copied.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a natively Windows folder replicator across drives.

Consider how this is done with a Windows Server (including very sensitive folders / files).

Keep your documents on a central machine. Make sure Windows is secure (good passwords).

Make usernames and passwords on this machine of other machines that can access. Then the other machines can access and use files.

You can set some folders to be restricted.

You can set other folders (like passports) to be read only.

Given that you cannot replicate drives (and even with a 3rd party tool, replicating 3 or more drives (folders) could lead to orphan files), this method of a server approach will work better for you.

Comment: If it is not possible to do this directly with a tool, is it possible to create a shell script that reads the contents of a directory and keeps them in sync over the network? On Linux using SSH, I can think of ways to do this.

Comment: You can sync files with something like Sync Back Pro (( i use this) but keeping 3 systems in sync in any OS can be problematic if A changes, B syncs and C changes while B is syncing. So that approach is problematic and a server-like approach is better.